# 'Code' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: command, external

C:>code .
'code' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

v12.18.4

6.14.8

git version 2.23.0.windows.1

path: C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\

Where am I wrong? Why can't I run the "code" command. from the command line?

Pls help.

Comment: C:\>echo %PATH%
C:\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Python38\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\

Answer (score 0):

What I understand with `code .` is that it opens the folder in the current directory in Visual Studio Code IDE. First check if Visual Studio is installed and try running it again from the windows terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This error message typically occurs when you try to run a command in the command prompt or terminal that is not recognized as a valid command.

In this case, the error message is indicating that the command 'code' is not recognized as a valid command.

Assuming that you are trying to run the Visual Studio Code editor using the 'code' command, this error message can occur if the VS Code executable file is not in your system's PATH environment variable.

To resolve this issue, you can try adding the path to the VS Code executable file to your system's PATH environment variable. To do this:

Open the Start menu and search for "Environment Variables" and select "Edit the system environment variables".
Click on the "Environment Variables" button at the bottom.
Scroll down to the "System Variables" section and find the "Path" variable. Click on "Edit".
Click on "New" and add the path to the directory where the VS Code executable file is located (e.g., "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code").
Click "OK" to close all windows and save the changes.
After adding the path to the VS Code executable file to your system's PATH environment variable, try running the 'code' command again in the command prompt or terminal. It should now be recognized as a valid command and launch the VS Code editor.